# HTML5: rectangle, counter-directional gradients for fill and border

Tags: html, css, border, gradient, fill

Is it possible to create a rect, that has gradient fill from black top to white bottom with gradient border from white top to black bottom?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also hypothetically possible using css gradients for the background-image and border image. I still suck at getting the border-image syntax correct but here's a half-figured out fiddle with a gradient for a border-image: http://jsfiddle.net/y8uFu/

You can dig through the spec for border-image here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images

I'd love to see if someone can figure it out for the border-image.

Comment: Alas, FF doesn't support it. Safari does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is most definitely possible. "Canvas" is what you are looking for.

Here are a few resourcses to get you started:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-introducing-canvas/
- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html#divingin
- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#gradients